# Sonos search results are disabled

Tags: soap, sonos

I've implemented a basic search into my Sonos app, but the results are disabled and not accessible:

[image: Screenshot of search result]

### Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
   <soap:Body>
      <searchResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
         <searchResult>
            <index>0</index>
            <count>1</count>
            <total>1</total>
            <mediaMetadata>
               <id>Artist:phish</id>
               <itemType>artist</itemType>
               <title>Phish</title>
               <authrequired>0</authrequired>
               <canPlay>false</canPlay>
            </mediaMetadata>
         </searchResult>
      </searchResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m guessing that you want that Phish result to be a container in to which a user can browse. In that case, you should be returning `mediaCollection` objects and not `mediaMetadata`.